# How to align middle-align text in a parbox?

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment, boxes, align

I am trying to add a frame around a text which would be centered and vertically aligned to the middle of the box but I can only center the text.

What should I do to align the text to the middle of the box?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{letter}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent\fbox{\parbox{\linewidth\fboxrule\fboxsep}{\center\textbf{my text here}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question `\fbox{{\parbox{.5\linewidth}{\centering\rule{1cm}{2cm}}}}` looks vertically aligned to me. Did you take  into account the  `y` descender of the `my text here` in asserting the vertical centering?

Comment: It depends on what you type, I had something else written in it and it was not vertically centered. There was more space at the top of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{letter}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}


\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][4in][c]{\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
    \centering\textbf{my text here}
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Almost, I had to take off the "-2" because it would write "-2 -2" before my text.

Comment: Did you use the `calc` package?  That might be why -2 showed up.

Comment: No, I didn't. I will try with it.